# ADF popups with datepicker

Tags: datepicker, popup, oracle-adf, popupwindow, jdeveloper

I have a problem with popups and date pickers in ADF. I have a task-flow with one page and in this page i call another task-flow (using a dialog popup).

When I select a date input field the "calendar" appears inside the popup with scroll (the calendar is bigger than the popup). The popup has 800px width and 250px height.

One solution is increase the size of the window but is not my preferred option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't specify width or height, the dialog by default will expand to cover the content, make sure also you don't set the stretchFirstChild attribute as well.